# Print out elements from an Array with a Comma between the elements

Tags: java, arrays, string, formatting

I am printing out elements from an `ArrayList` and want to have a comma after each word except the last word.

Right now, I am doing it like this:

```
for (String s : arrayListWords) {
    System.out.print(s + ", ");
}
```

It prints out the words like this:

```
one, two, three, four,
```

The problem is the last comma. How do I solve it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could just invoke `toString()` on your `ArrayList` and it will return the `toString()` of each element in your array separated by a comma. If you don't like the `[` and `]`, you could just take those out. Something like [this](http://ideone.com/wBmvua)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Print the first word on its own if it exists. Then print the pattern as comma first, then the next element.

```
if (arrayListWords.length >= 1) {
    System.out.print(arrayListWords[0]);
}

// note that i starts at 1, since we already printed the element at index 0
for (int i = 1; i < arrayListWords.length, i++) { 
     System.out.print(", " + arrayListWords[i]);
}
```

With a `List`, you're better off using an `Iterator`

```
// assume String
Iterator<String> it = arrayListWords.iterator();
if (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(it.next());
}
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(", " + it.next());
}
```

Comment: @Erica You edited your post to say it's an array list (or I misread it). You'll have to change how you iterate to fit the `List` api.

Comment: Note that if the `arrayListWords` is a `LinkedList` rather than an `ArrayList` then this becomes an `O(n^2)` solution when it should be an `O(n)`.

Comment: Pure ArrayList, Spidey, but thanks for letting me know the complexity!

Answer (score 20):

I would write it this way:

```
String separator = "";  // separator here is your ","

for (String s : arrayListWords) {
    System.out.print(separator + s);
    separator = ",";
}
```

If arrayListWords has two words, it should print out
A,B

Answer (score 17):

Using Java 8 Streams:

```java
Stream.of(arrayListWords).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: how about for int[] int array? thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
StringJoiner str = new StringJoiner(", ");
str.add("Aplha").add("Beta").add("Gamma");

String result = str.toString();
System.out.println("The result is: " + result);
```

*The output:
The result is: Aplha, Beta, Gamma*

Answer (score 3):

While iterating, you can append the `String s` to the `StringBuilder` and at the end, you can delete the last 2 chars which is an extra `,` and a space (`res.length() -2`)

```
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : arrayListWords) {
    res.append(s).append(", ");
}
System.out.println(res.deleteCharAt(res.length()-2).toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 it got much easier, no need for 3rd parties -

```
final List<String> words = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");
Optional<String> wordsAsString = words.stream().reduce((w1, w2) -> w1 + "," + w2);
wordsAsString.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Your solution works as expected, but I get a warning by SonarLint: `Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value.`
I am not super confident with lambda expressions yet, would you know how to use `.ifPresent()` here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a standard function in the java.util package and remove the block quotes at start and end.

```
String str = java.util.Arrays.toString(arrayListWords);
str = str.substring(1,str.length()-1);
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Iterator` on the `List` to check whether there are more elements.

You can then append the comma only if the current element is not the last element.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<String> words = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four"});

    final Iterator<String> wordIter = words.iterator();
    final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    while (wordIter.hasNext()) {
        out.append(wordIter.next());
        if (wordIter.hasNext()) {
            out.append(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(out.toString());
}
```

However it is much easier to use a 3rd party library like [Guava](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guava) to do this for you. The code then becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<String> words = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four"});
    System.out.println(Joiner.on(",").join(words));
}
```

Comment: I will take a look on Guava when I become more experienced, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    List<String> listWords= Arrays.asList(arrayListWords); // convert array to List
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(listWords);
    System.out.println(sb.toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]",""));
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the `toString` value of the `List` in your program logic. This may change from implementation to implementation causing the code to break.

Comment: this will also remove the characters from words, if any of the words contains '[' or ']' this will change the word.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the toString() method.

```
String s = arrayListWords.toString();
System.out.println(s);

//This will print it like this: "[one, two, three, four]"
//If you want to remove the brackets you can do so easily. Just change the way you print.
```

Comment: Could you explain "the way you print"? Is there any option to print without the brackets?

Comment: The user posted that it's an array list. You can use toString() on array lists.

Comment: Use this:

int length = s.length();
s = s.substring(1,length);

System.out.println(s);

Comment: @Erica you could also try this:

s = s.replace("[","").replace("]","");

This is a shorter way to do this. :)

Comment: Good one @Rahul, this will definitely get used!

Comment: @Erica this solution is best for Java as they've given us already defined method of "toString()".
But in general, without the use of any methods, use the answer you've chosen above. I had done the same thing when I had written a similar code in C.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I come up with:

```
String join = "";

// solution 1
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"});
for(String s: strList) {
   int idx = strList.indexOf(s);
   join += (idx == strList.size()-1) ? s : s + ",";
}
System.out.println(join);

// solution 2 
join = "";
for(String s: strList) {    
   join += s + ",";
}

join = join.substring(0, join.length()-1);
System.out.println(join);

// solution 3  
join = "";
int count = 0;
for(String s: strList) {    
   join += (count == strlist.size()-1) ? s: s + ",";
   count++;
}

System.out.println(join);
```

off course we can utalise `StringBuilder` but of all solutions, I like `@Mav` answer as it's more efficient and clean.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the most efficient means of comma-delimited string using best practices and no "if" checks, no unfamiliar libraries, and `StringBuilder` which is best practice for concatenating strings.

Also having a "size" variable reduces the calls to the `.size()` method.

For those using `String[]`:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String[] strArr = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
int size = strArr.length;
str.append(strArr[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    str.append(",").append(strArr[i]);
}
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

For those using `ArrayList<String>`:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
List<String> strArr = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four"});
int size = strArr.size();
str.append(strArr.get(0));
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    str.append(",").append(strArr.get(i));
}
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

Both yield: `one,two,three,four`

Answer (score 0):

Since the second-to-top question was wrong, here's a little method I wrote to do this with an array of Integers but converted to array of Strings.

```
    public static void printArray(String[] arr){
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
        if(i<(arr.length-1))
            System.out.print(",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done using Java 8 `static` method `String.join()`, which comes in two flavors.

> Returns a new `String` composed of copies of the `CharSequence` elements joined together with a copy of the specified `delimiter`.

Both versions expect as the first argument `delimiter` of type `CharSequence`, and as the second argument we can provide either *varargs* of `CharSequence` or `Iterable<? extends CharSequence>`.

Both methods generate under the hood a `byte`-array filled byte representations of the provided *elements* and *delimiter* according to their encoding and then turn it into the resulting `String`.

*Example with* [`String.join(CharSequence,CharSequence...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)):

```
String[] strings = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

String joinedStr = String.join(", ", strings); // "one, two, three, four" - resulting String
```

*Example with* [`String.join(CharSequence,Iterable<? extends CharSequence>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable)):

```
List<String> strings = List.of("one", "two", "three", "four");

String joinedStr = String.join(", ", strings); // "one, two, three, four" - resulting String
```