# Insert semicolon between items from an array except the last

Tags: java, loops

Based from the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18279659/1919069) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18279622/1919069), I have this code:

```
if (authors.length >= 1) {
    System.out.print(authors[0]);
}

for (int i = 1; i < authors.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("; " + authors[i]);
}
```

So the output of this is `author1; author2; author3`
How can I change this into `author1; author2 & author3`? If there are only 2 authors, the output should be `author1 & author2`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd just need to add in one conditional to your loop to handle the last case:

```
for (int i = 1; i < authors.length; i++) {
    if(i == authors.length - 1)
        System.out.print("& " + authors[i]);
    else
        System.out.print("; " + authors[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be changing the structure of the code to use a loop and a `boolean` flag instead of a conditional, like this:

```
boolean isFirst = true;
for (int i = 0 ; i != authors.length ; i++) {
    if (!isFirst) {
        System.out.print(i == authors.length-1 ? "& " : "; ");
    } else {
         isFirst = false;
    }
    System.out.print(authors[i]);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/lvN4V7)

Comment: Then would this not be an infinite loop, continuing after `i > authors.length`? Or does it break the loop at the first instance of the condition not being met? (i being equal to authors.length)

Comment: @CalebB This would break on the first instance of the condition not being met, it would not be infinite.  All loops stop iterating as soon as a false is calculated from the loop expression.

Comment: @CalebB There is no way to make an array `authors` that turns this loop into an infinite one. The only way to break `i != authors.length` would be to make `authors.length` negative, which is, of course, not possible.

Comment: How is `? : ` this called again? I know it has something to do with boolean.

Comment: @WonderWorld That's a conditional operator (also known as the "ternary operator").

Answer (score 2):

You can do it recursively to separate cases clearly. Seems like other answers lack that.

This is the proxy function:

```
public static String doIt(String[] authors){

    if (authors == null || authors.length == 0){
        return "";
    }

    if (authors.length == 1){
        return authors[0];
    }

    return authors[0] + doHelper(authors, 1);

}
```

And the helper function:

```
public static String doItHelper(String[] authors, int index){
    if (index == authors.length - 1){
        return " & " + authors[index];
    }
    return "; " + authors[index] + doItHelper(authors, index + 1);

}
```

As mentioned in comments (Thanks @JNYRanger) this is **not** optimal when performance is an issue.

Can't test it now, so I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: It's extremely unnecessary and wasteful to use recursion for an insanely simple algorithm in Java.  If this was Haskell, then this would be a great idea...but for Java, no.

Comment: @JNYRanger you're optimizing what should not be optimized. **That's** wasteful.

Comment: @ReutSharabani How is concerving your resources and coding smart wasteful? You could write a every string adding one character at a time but why would you?

Comment: @CalebB If this works and is easy to follow why do it any other way? Are you going to concatenate millions of authors? Are you experiencing performance issues? If you do, you should bother with optimizations. This is probably not the case and **you** think a loop is easier while **I** think this is.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with you on that front Reut.  But using the proper semantics for a specific language is not optimization.  Of course recursion has it's place in Java, but I would disagree that this is not one of them.  Additionally, the standard JVM by Oracle does not currently provide tail-call optimization, so keep that in mind as well.

Comment: @JNYRanger let's just agree to disagree. Though, if you look at other answers, this is the only one that separates and handles all cases simply. The only way tail call optimizations should even be considered as an interesting topic in our context is if you're experiencing performance issues.

Comment: Fair enough.  For this trivial case it doesn't really matter either way.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
    String[] authors = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {

        sb.append(authors[i]);
        if (i + 2 < authors.length) {
            sb.append(";");
        } else if (i + 2 == authors.length) {
            sb.append("&");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i += 1) {
    if (i > 0) {
        System.out.print(i < authors.length - 1 ? "; " : " & ");
    }
    System.out.print(authors[i]);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] authors = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {
   System.out.print((i != 0 ? (i == authors.length - 1 ? " & " : "; ") : "") + authors[i]);
}
```